# Is it possible to get a RandomAccessStream from a MediaStreamSource?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Is it possible to get an IRandomAccessStream or really any stream from Windows::Storage::Streams from a MediaStreamSource? I am not totally sure how a MediaStreamSource differs from these other more common types of streams.

Comment: No, the `MediaStreamSource` does not contain a reference to the stream.